# Error: 302 Response code json

Tags: php, ajax, json, response, status

```
      productName  = (typeof(productName) != 'undefined' && productName != '') ? productName : '';
      userId       = (typeof(userId) != 'undefined' && userId != '') ? userId : '';
      settingsData = (typeof(settingsData) != 'undefined' && settingsData != '') ? settingsData : '';


             $.ajax({
                              type    : "GET",
                              dataType: "json",
                              url     : baseUrl + url,
                              data    : {
                                   productColumnName : productName,
                                   targetId          : userId,
                                   settingsData      : settingsData
                               }
                           }).done(function( response ) {
                               checkLogout(response);
                               location.reload();
                           }).fail(function() {
                               location.reload();
                           });
```

I have call url to renew the page but i get 302 get response

**METHOD = GET
STATUS = 302**

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: please check your url into direct what error i will show ?

Comment: pls give a fiddle code

Comment: I am trying to renew/refresh page after clicking on keep me sign in

Answer (score 1):

It isn't completely clear what your question is.  The 302 is a redirect code (meaning the that web page didn't download in a completely normal fashion).  This means that the URL has an intermediate step before the packets are downloaded.  If you own and control the first URL that is called, then that URL is redirecting to another URL.  Maybe you need to construct the URL differently to bypass the intermediate URL.  But this assumes that a 302 code is fatal to what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I am trying to renew/refresh page after clicking on keep me sign in.

Comment: I want to refresh the page using ajax jquery thats it

Answer (score 0):

```
productName  = (typeof(productName) != 'undefined' && productName != '') ? productName : '';
      userId       = (typeof(userId) != 'undefined' && userId != '') ? userId : '';
      settingsData = (typeof(settingsData) != 'undefined' && settingsData != '') ? settingsData : '';


             $.ajax({
                              type    : "GET",
                              dataType: "json",
                              url     : baseUrl + url,
                              data    : {
                                   productColumnName : productName,
                                   targetId          : userId,
                                   settingsData      : settingsData
                               }
                           }).done(function( response ) {
                               checkLogout(response);
                               location.reload();
                           }).fail(function() {
                               location.reload();
                           });
```

I got it
URL was wrong due to that it gives 302